# Looping through a range to find a value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have a worksheet that has columns 1-8, rows 3 through the last row. I would like to loop through each cell to find out if a value of 1 is present. If it is then that row is copied and inserted for each value of 1, additionally that new row will have a text inserted in cell (13,row) then moved to the next row. This is as far as I got....thanks!

```
Sub Workcenter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo 0
Dim Test                                As Worksheet

   
Set TS = Worksheets("Test")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
For k = 1 To 8
For j = 4 To TS.Cells(Rows.Count, k).End(xlUp).Row
If TS.Cells(j, k).Value = 1 Then TS.Cells.Activate
'TS.Cells.Activate.Row.Select
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
'ShopOrderNumRow = j
Next j
Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what's going on... what is being inserted and where?  If you're inserting, then you would be moving the location of cells, which causes an issue for your loop.

Comment: Also, why check for a value of `1` in each cell of a row and not just use `Find()` for the row, to determine if `cells(row,13).value` needs to be updated?

Comment: I have a range of rows & columns 1-8 that I'm scanning, each may contain a 1 or nothing with 1 signifying that the operation is scheduled. The intent is to copy the parent row and past that information below how many times "1" is present. I would like to start from the top down to the last row. After that I begin to populate that row with other data.

Comment: So you want to `countif(val,1)` and insert that many times?  You would want to do a reverse loot (`step -1`) for this, as each insert will adjust you row number (assuming `for rowNum = lastRow to firstRow`) if you were to go from first to last.

Comment: Cyril, Yes, stepping from the bottom up may be the idea way to go. I would like to insert a copied rows as many times as (1) is present in that row for that range.

Comment: See my edit in answer; that should be about where you want to be

Comment: I'm running into a problem but should give you more information as to what the count should be doing. I would like to count how many times 1 appears per row in the range ("A3: LastRow). That will be how many times the row is copied then inserted, the next step will have to skip that many rows to the next count (going from last to first row). The text that is inserted into the copied row's cell (13) is taken from the header identifying that operation's name at the top of the range, say (row 2, columns 1-8). I had some problems with the previous code but want to thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will try giving some example knowing that I still don't understand how the inserting is occurring for each cell of a row.

Providing more detail, or example of before/after in your post may help.

As for an example, since you're marking only a single cell in each row, I would suggest `Find()` for value of `1` to determine if you need to write to that specific cell.

```
'untested code
sub test()
    toggle false
    dim rowNum as long
    for rowNum = firstRow to lastRow Step 1
        with sheets(1)
            with .range(.cells(rowNum,1),.cells(rowNum,8))
                dim foundCell as range
                set foundCell = .find(1)
                if not foundCell is nothing then .cells(rowNum,13).value = "text"
            end with
        end with
    next iterator
    toggle true
end sub

private sub toggle(val as boolean)
    with application
        .screenupdating = val
        .enableevents = val
    end with
end sub
```

---

**Edit1**:  Looks like `countif()` may be the saviour here.
**Edit2**:  Tested code input (untested code part of Edit1)

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastRow As Long:  lastRow = 10
    Dim firstRow As Long:  firstRow = 1
    toggle False
    Dim rowNum As Long
    For rowNum = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
        With Sheets(1)
            Dim countRange As Range
            Set countRange = .Range(.Cells(rowNum, 1), .Cells(rowNum, 8))
            Dim countOfOnes As Long
            countOfOnes = Application.CountIf(countRange, 1)
            If countOfOnes > 0 Then
                With .Rows(rowNum)
                    .Copy
                    .Offset(1).Resize(countOfOnes).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End With
                .Cells(rowNum, 13).Value = "text"
            End If
        End With
    Next rowNum
    toggle True
End Sub

Private Sub toggle(val As Boolean)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = val
        .EnableEvents = val
    End With
End Sub
```

Tested using this data:

[image]

Output from running code:

[image]

Comment: Running into issues with the code. It does not copy & duplicate the number of rows based on the sum of the row but for the sum of the range. Wondering if SUMIF or COUNTIFS may work.....thanks

Comment: @GSpencer Can you post your updated code in your question? Any mock-up of the data would also be appreciated, indicating before/after.   Updated my Edit with tested code and example info.

Comment: Please see the attached comments & edits. The value of 1 determines what operation is being scheduled for that particular order, hence the need to copy the row with the text value in cell 13. That's the reference for the operation ID. I am trying to move from a static to a dynamic system using those modifications......thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. You were right with the CountIf code.

Comment: @GSpencer glad that helped out; if this resolved your issues, please check as answered.